# Using matched string of wildcard in a bash command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, conversion

I want to convert an entire folder of bmp files to png and was just wondering if that would be possible with a one liner in bash or if I need a script for that.

Can I access the string matched by the wildcard before like this, so that e.g. `lena.bmp` it converts to `lena.png`:

```
convert *.bmp <matchedString>.png
```

Comment: any bash scripts can be a one-liner if you replace newlines with `;` readability is another issue

Comment: Can the file names contain spaces, tabs or line breaks?

Comment: yes they can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert *.bmp something.png` will expand to *all* the bmp files:

```sh
convert a.bmp b.bmp c.bmp ... z.bmp something.png
```

If you want to map them all 1:1, you need a loop:

```sh
for b in *.bmp; do
    p=${b%.bmp}.png
    convert "$b" "$p"
done
```

See [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)